# My phone is receiving ~1700mA but it's slow at charging

Tags: battery, charging, xiaomi, redmi

I have 2 Xiaomi phones that both have **18W** fast-charging and receive around **1700mA** while charging, but one of them takes a long time to charge (even if i change the USB cable).

How does that make any sense?

Comment: Hello. What does [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere) app report? Make sure to observe current in it for at least a minute.

Comment: How do you know the phones receive 1700mA?

Comment: @Firelord I already measured it using Ampere for at least 2.5min

Comment: @Robert Using the Ampere APP :D

Comment: 1700mA is AFAIR not a very high charging current (less than 8 Watt). You should check out what high charging modes your phones support: proprietary or USB PD with what voltage power levels or the new USB PD where the phone can define any voltage level. And then do the same for the charger. Both parts have to match e.g. the charget may provide 9.0V max. 2.0A=18W but then the phone also have to support charging with 9V using the same standard.